# Convertir array en objeto

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array

```js
0: {id_programa_educativo: 38}
1: {id_programa_educativo: 39}
2: {id_programa_educativo: 40}
```

el cual deseo convertirlo o pasarlo de esta manera para guardarlo en un [(ngModel)] donde mi valor es numerico.

```
[38, 39, 40]
```

alguien sabe cómo ??

intente con el push, pero me devuelve lo mismo.

Comment: No será convertir objeto a array?...

Comment: es un arreglo de objetos? muestra bien cómo se ve completo el array

Comment: Si es un array de objetos, lo puedes hacer con `const result = variable.map(x => x.id_programa_educativo)` donde `variable` es el nombre de la variable que tiene el contenido del array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu tienes un objeto, con [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) obtienes una array de los valores de dicho objecto. es decir

```
[ {id_programa_educativo: 38},
{id_programa_educativo: 39},
{id_programa_educativo: 40}
}];
```

Luego con un [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), puedes obtener los valores de cada unos de los objetos resultantes

```js
let obj = {
0: {id_programa_educativo: 38},
1: {id_programa_educativo: 39},
2: {id_programa_educativo: 40}
};

let array = Object.values(obj).map(a=>a.id_programa_educativo);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo @Yussef ya quedo resulto esta parte de verdad que te agradezco muchísimo mi estimado.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que mapear a los objetos que están dentro para poder ingresar a sus valores y posteriormente estos valores se almacenarán en un nuevo arreglo, sería algo así:

```js
let object = {
  0: { id_programa_educativo: 38 },
  1: { id_programa_educativo: 39 },
  2: { id_programa_educativo: 40 },
};

let result = Object.values(object).map(valor=>valor.id_programa_educativo)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo @Cris223511 ya quedo resulto esta parte de verdad que te agradezco muchísimo por tú tiempo.

Comment: Si estimado, mucho gusto poder ayudarle, saludos.